# Rendering form partials from other controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a few shared partials that I can render from any controller fine however I am having a bit of trouble rendering form partials from another controller. I am wanting to be able to add notes to my contacts

In my contacts/show.html.erb i have the following

```
<% render :partial => "notes/form", :note => Note.new %>
```

In my notes/_form.html.erb i have the following

```
<%= form_for @note do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :contact_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :contact_id %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

However I get the  error:

Showing /Applications/Rails/apps/saas31/app/views/notes/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @note do |f| %>
2:   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

I'm starting to get the hang of rails but having a few small frustrating problems as to be expected when learning anything new i suppose. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your local variables should be passed through in a locals hash.

```
<% render :partial => "notes/form", :locals => {:note => Note.new} %>
```

[Read section 3.4.4 here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Your partial also shouldn't use instance variables, change the following:

```
<%= form_for @note do |f| %>
```

to:

```
<%= form_for note do |f| %>
```

**edit**

If you want to use an instance variable, you can do the following:

```
<% render :partial => "notes/form", :locals => {:note => @note} %>
```

Comment: Yes and additionally rewrite the partial to use 'note' instead of '@note' (Remember update any existing views which call the partial to use the (:locals => ...) form).

Comment: Thanks guys that works! The only problem is that now none of the CRUD action on the notes controller that uses that form works because they declare an instance variable. Do I need to rewrite these actions to explicitly pass in the node variable when they render? is this the best practices?

Comment: Thank you, Gazler!

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue and this post was helpful in solving.  Adding my notes and hopefully it will help someone else :)

I had a a Users controller and a _form.html.erb that rendered fine when I would access the /users/new page.  I was trying to render the form as a partial from my /layouts/application.html.erb, as I wanted to give users the ability to create a new user from any page.

I ended up creating a new method (new_user) in application_helper.rb. Here is the code:

```
def new_user
  User.new    
end
```

I then render the partial from application.html.erb with:

```
<%= render :partial => 'users/form', :locals => {:user => new_user} %>
```